# How is bonus money collected in The Last of Us?

Tags: the-last-of-us

After finishing my first playthrough of The Last of Us (hard difficulty), I found that I had accrued $4500 in money that could be used for bonus content (i.e. skins, render modes, art). How did I get this? And I how do I get more? Are there specific challenges to complete? Is the money linked to the trophies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The money is gained by completing challenges. You should be able to find them under Bonuses -> Tags in the menu system. You collect money (amount of which varies with challenge it seems) for every challenge completed. Some of the challenges are associated with trophies, but the money you earn from that is not linked to any trophies, neither are the unlockables that you purchase with the money you've earned.

Answer (score -1):

No. You can buy stuff on the menu screen, but it goes to Bonus. There you can  buy clothes and backpacks for Joel and Ellie (only affect the appearance of the character).

Comment: This is an old answer but came up in a review. If you intended for this to stick around, I would return and edit it to be a bit more clear. As it's currently written, it's difficult to tell precisely what you're trying to say.

Comment: @Spevacus This user hasn't been seen in years. It's been eight years since this answer was made, so I doubt they'll be back any time soon.

Comment: @BoogaRoo Yeah, but I figured I'd leave a comment in the highly unlikely event they ever come back.