# Does tag progress carry across playthroughs?

Tags: the-last-of-us

In addition to the PlayStation trophies you can earn in The Last of Us, you can also earn tags, which reward you with "money" you can spend on bonus unlocks. Some of the tags have requirements like killing 50 enemies with nail bombs.

Does progress toward tag completion carry across playthroughs, or perhaps only into a new game+? Do they carry over multiple games?

Comment: My default assumption would be yes, as you have to access tags via Bonuses in the menu system outside the context of saved games: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121585/how-is-bonus-money-collected-in-the-last-of-us It would be bad menu/game design otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that tag progress does carry over, at least from one game into the new game plus. I don't know whether the same holds true in an entirely new game.